# Problem with Dictionary<string, List<IRp>>, overwriting data

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Hi I store chat conversation in property type of:

```
  public Dictionary<string, List<IRp>> History { get; set; }
```

Key is nick and List is collection which contains history of communication.

I use on store this SaveRp method, IRp is interface which implements message class.

```
    public void SaveRp(IRp rp)
    {
        if (!History.ContainsKey(rp.Nick))
        {
            History.Add(rp.Nick, new List<IRp> { rp });
        }
        else
        {
            History[rp.Nick].Add(rp);
        }
    }
```

Problem is I store messages in this sequence for one and the same Nick(Tom for example) :

## 1 message text:  Hello

## 2 message text:  how

## 3 message text:  are

## 4 message text:  you?

Problem is if I load history for this nick, with this method:

```
    public IList<IRp> GetRps(string nick)
    {
        var result=new List<IRp>();
        if (History.ContainsKey(nick))
        {
           result= History[nick];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I get this:

## 1 message text:  you?

## 2 message text:  you?

## 3 message text:  you?

## 4 message text:  you?

I think bug must be in SaveRp method and and somehow overwriting / rewrite

Comment: We need to see more code. Do you create a new instance of IRp each time or just edit the existing one?

Comment: Consider using the TryGet method of dictionary to avoid double dictionary lookups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is likely to be that you are updating the same Rp object that is being added to the list.  When it is added to the list, a reference to the object is added, wich means if it is changed, then the data in the list changes.

After you save your Rp, you should create a new instance.

Also, class names, interfaces and properties should use full names, not abbreviations to allow anyone else that ever goes near your code to understand what is happening.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. Looks like the OP is using the same instance of `IRp`.

Comment: Thank, I use all the time same instance for message class, and only change the  string property of this class. If I create for every message new object it solved this problme, Sory for  my english.